# Microsoft Active Directory LDAP - Error - (UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM) - 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A12DD, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM)

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to create user with api-all.1.0.3.jar LdapConnection object using add method.
I have two servers where with one server it is working fine and with other server it is giving me this error:

```
MessageType : ADD_RESPONSE
Message ID : 2
    Add Response
        Ldap Result
            Result code : (UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM) unwillingToPerform
            Matched Dn : ''
            Diagnostic message : '0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A12DD, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
```

I have checked that my user has full rights in Microsoft AD.
Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is the replication happening successfully on both the servers?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by replication? Also want to know what this error code is: DSID-031A12DD

Comment: "Unwilling to perform" usually means that some of the data you're trying to write is wrong.

Comment: @AmitGawali - You can check this page: https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/kb/how-to/how-to-check-if-domain-controllers-are-in-sync-with-each-other.html, to understand what the replication status is. I don't know about the error code!

Comment: ok. I will see. Thanks for your help.

Comment: if it helps someone: the password should be quoted and sent in bytes with UTF-16LE encode.